# Stop a jQueryUI effect

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm developing a kind of chat similar the Facebook one. I used the jQuery UI highlight effect when a new message arrives. Now I want to stop this effect when the user click on the windows.

This is my code on window click event. The "janela" class is the chat's windows.

```
$('.janela').live('click', function(){
    var id = $(this).children('.topo').attr('id');
    $.post('sys/chat.php',{acao: 'mudar_status', user: id});
    $(".topo").effect("none"); //it's just a frustrated try.
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: live is deprecated.  Use `on`.

Comment: you can call `.stop(true, true)`

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Zn665/

Answer (score 0):

Use [`stop`:](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

```
$(".topo").stop(true, true)
```

As mentioned in my comment, `live` is deprecated, use `on`.

Comment: I can't use stop beacuse it stops also my script that get messages. Thanks about the "on". I will edit my code.

Answer (score 0):

Use [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/), it stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements.

```
$(".topo").stop(true, true);
```

Comment: I can't use stop beacuse it stops also my script that get messages.